Simple function to check whether a word is palindrome or not
I'm still new to python. It'll be really helpful if someone can point out what's wrong in the code here.
def palindrome(s):
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        x = (s[i] == s[-1-i])
        if x == True:
            return x
        else:
            x = False
            return x
            break

def palindrome(s):
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        x = (s[i] == s[-1-i])
        if x == True:
            return x
        else:
            return x
            break

palindrome('loll')

Using this function returns True instead of False.

return stops the function execution, so you only loop once.

Does this answer your question? what is difference between returning return from inside loop and outside loop?

BTW, because x is the result of a comparison, if it's not True, it should be False, so there's no need to assign that value explicitly.

Also, if you are going to return x whether it's True or False, there's no need to check it's value, just return it as it is. Anyway, you probably will have to make this check for your palindrome function once you fix it's logic.

Please think carefully about the logic of the code. If x == True, will the loop continue? If x == False, will the loop continue? (Hint: When you call a function, how many times do you think it can return, per time that it is called?)

You're always returning on the first iteration of your loop. This means the loop only executes once. If the first and last letter are equal it will determine you have a palindrome.
But you can only short-circuit on finding a mis-match, so you should only return early in this situation. Should the loop end without an early return we know we have a valid palindrome, so we can safely return True.
def palindrome(s):
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        x = (s[i] == s[-1-i])
        if not x:
            return False
    return True

But you really only need to iterate halfway, and assigning to x is unnecessary.
def palindrome(s):
    for i in range(0, len(s) // 2):
        if s[i] != s[-1-i]:
            return False
    return True

To further refine this, all implements this kind of short-circuiting, and we can feed it a generator expression.
def palindrome(s):
    return all(
        s[i] == s[-1 - i]
        for i in range(len(s) // 2)
    )


You don't need that break, return already stops the loop.
def palindrome(word):
    for i in range (0,len(word)):    
        is_pal = (word[i] == word[-1-i])
        if not is_pal:
            return is_pal
    return is_pal

This should work.

Thanks. I'll keep the variable naming in mind.

I'm glad I could help this is actually my first answer. (:

Please check the indentation.

Note that this will raise an exception about is_pal not being defined if you pass an empty string to palindrome.

oh yeah it would break if you put in an empty string. i guess you could just check if its not an empty string before you do anything, there might be a better method but im still kinda new to python but not too new
